# Comparing Values from two different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

so I have two different worksheets that have a column with Service Orders. Basically what I am trying to do if the numbers in SO-ID column from Worksheet1 matches the SO# column in Worksheet2, then I want to the copy those corresponding columns, "Order" and "Type", associated with that specific Service Order Number from Worksheet2 to the Worksheet1. Any help would greatly appreciated. I showed an example below but there are plenty more data points than that is shown:

```
   Worksheet1 named "In Progress":

    Region  SO-ID   Site ID
    C01    5818476  DNYF8766D
    E01    5975844  DCD00139
    E01    5446828  DEG02219

.
.
.
.
.


Worksheet B named "0205":

No. SO#             Order     Type
1   5446828       KMC07570    Re-Install
2   5975844       KSS10269A   Install
3   5818476        KSS10349D    Re-Install
.
.
.
.


Results:

In Worksheet1 named "In Progress":

Region  SO-ID   Site ID     Order     Type
C01    5818476  DNYF8766D   KSS10349D   Re-Install
E01    5975844  DCD00139    KSS10269A     Install
E01    5446828  DEG02219    KMC07570      Re-Install
.
.
.
.
.
```

This is the code I wrote, but it doesn't work

```
Sub DCompare()
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long


For i = LR To 2 Step -1
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i) Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 8).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 9).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4).Value
End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I never really used VLOOKUP formula but the reason I didn't try it is because I want a macro that will help me apply this to other worksheets in the future.

Comment: Will there be more than one occurrence of SO-ID in Worksheet B?

Comment: @ barryleajo  Sorry I didn't fully understand the question but if you are asking if there are more than one columns with Service orders then the answer is no. The service orders in Worksheet B is under column titled "SO#". The service orders in Worksheet A is under column titled "SO-ID". ALL the service orders in worksheet B are in Worksheet A but not in the same order. But not all the service orders in Worksheet A are in Worksheet B. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: No - rather I mean't that if we searched Workbook B for SO-ID 5818476, will 5818476 appear more than once in the Worksheet B SO# column?

Comment: oh sorry i misunderstood. No it wont appear more than once. Only one of each service orders exist for each row.

Comment: VLOOKUP would be **so much better** than a macro here...so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that each comparison you are making would have to match row-for-row before you accepted a match. Better to search the target for the match and record the row to be used in transferring the data.

```
Sub DCompare()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, t As Long, ws2 As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws2 = .Sheets("Sheet2")
        With .Sheets("Sheet1")
            LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = LR To 2 Step -1
                If CBool(Application.CountIf(ws2.Columns("B"), .Cells(i, "B").Value2)) Then
                    t = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "B").Value2, ws2.Columns("B"), 0)
                    ws2.Cells(t, 8).Resize(1, 2) = .Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 2).Value
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End With

    Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

That looks for a match and if one if found it captured the target matching row and transfers the two cells worth of information. I'm curious why you though it necessary to start at the bottom and work up but I suppose there could be hierarchy of information that wasn't disclosed. Might have been easier to avoid transferring the data if the reasons for working backwards were disclosed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will test this out and report back. Also there was no reason to start at the bottom. I am not the brilliant when it comes to macros so I got that line from some online blog I think. But if there is another way you thinnk it would be easier or faster, feel free to suggest. Again I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

A second example.  Uses a simple .Find on Worksheet B.  Incorporates some variables for you to position the data on each sheet, name worksheets etc. which may give you some flexibility to customise?

```
Option Explicit

Sub subFindSOID()
Dim wsSO As Worksheet, wsOrd As Worksheet
Dim SORng As Range, OrdRng As Range, fndSO As Range, c As Range
Dim SOStRow As Long, SOEndRow As Long, SOCol As Long, SOff As Long
Dim OrdStRow As Long, OrdEndRow As Long, OrdCol As Long

'Assign worksheets
Set wsSO = Worksheets("In Progress")
Set wsOrd = Worksheets("0205")

'Assign data start position on each sheet
SOStRow = 3
SOCol = 2

OrdStRow = 3
OrdCol = 2
SOff = 1

    'Get search range
    With wsOrd
        OrdEndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, OrdCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Set OrdRng = .Range(.Cells(OrdStRow, OrdCol), .Cells(OrdEndRow, OrdCol).Offset(0, SOff + 2))
    End With

    With wsSO
        'Get range to iterate
        SOEndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, SOCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Set SORng = .Range(.Cells(SOStRow, SOCol), .Cells(SOEndRow, SOCol))
            'Iterate the range
            For Each c In SORng.Offset(0, 1)
                Set fndSO = OrdRng.Find(What:=c, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                If Not fndSO Is Nothing Then
                    'Copy the data columns
                    c.Offset(0, 2).Value = fndSO.Offset(0, SOff).Value
                    c.Offset(0, 3).Value = fndSO.Offset(0, SOff + 1).Value
                End If
            Next c
    End With
End Sub
```